# Where the best place to manage pages?

Tags: flutter, dart

Page navigating documented in Flutter Docs case is very simple:

```
SomeButton(
  ...
  onPressed:()=>Navigator.push(...),
  ...
)
```

In more realistic cases app have to do some works before push some page. For example, auth check. So, real onPresses callback should look like:

```
SomeButton(
  ...
  onPressed:()=>signIn(),
  ...
)

...

//somewhere
void signIn() async{
  final bool isAuthed = await _auth.checkAuth(...);
  if (isAuthed){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, homePageName);
  } else {
    //for FutureBuilder.hasError
    throw NotAuthedException(); 
  }
}
```

In this place `UseCases` and `View`(widgets) responsibilities are merged. `checkAuth` is definitely `UseCases` responsibility.
But pushing page...

By one hand, `Navigator` requires `context`. `BuildContext` is definitely `View` responsibility. It should not have place in `UseCases`. But page navigating into app is definitely `UseCases` responsibility.

**How to clearly share responsibility?**

I think that callback `checkAuth` should take`BuildContext` from closure:

```
onPressed: ()=> context.watch<...>().signIn(context);
```

and in `UseCases`(throught `ViewModel`) context will used like:

```
class UseCases {
...
  Future<void> signIn(BuildContext context) async{
    try{
      final bool isAuthed = await _auth.checkAuth(...);
      if (isAuthed){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, homePageName);
      } else {
        throw NotAuthedException(); //for some FutureBuilder.hasError
      }
    } catch(e,s){
      ExceptionHandler.handle(e,s); //for app logic
      rethrow; //for some FutureBuilder.hasError. i.e view building
    }
  }
...
}
```

so, `context` is not a `UseCases` state. It lives only in `signIn`.

**Is it a good decision?**

Are there any cleaner decisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern I follow is rather to have a bloc that handles the logic, in your example that would be the Auth check. In the bloc I'd emit a new state, say a state called Authed, when `if (isAuthed)` pass.

In the view you could have a BlocListener that trigger on the state change to Authed and do your routing there or display a Snackbar or similar.

This way you don't have to mix view actions with logic that really doesn't require view information.

Comment: But state is ... a state!  If a do showing snackbar on some state (e.g. Authed), it will be shown every rebuild, but it is a one-time action. I can do checking how many times it was checked, but it is not true way. So, i think that i should push page or  show snackbars in use case.

Comment: No, BlocListener only triggers once there is a state change, not on every rebuild so your snackbar won't be displayed on each rebuild. BlocBuilder is (optionally) triggered on each rebuild. Note that you can use listenWhen and buildWhen parameters for the BlocListener and BlocBuilder respectively for more fine-grained control.